# External property file configuration on Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I created spring mvc application and also I have a external property file on D:\propertiesfile.properties , I need to know how to configure the property file in servlet-context.xml

```
 <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
<context:property-placeholder location="file:D:\propertiesfile.properties>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.properties" />
```

But its not working. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using spring boot if possible. In spring boot you can have an application.properties outside the compiled jar file without even defining where it is, because spring boot finds it by itself. It also comes with autoconfiguration, so basicly "xml" and much configuration overhead "dies". And you can do configuration if necessarry very easy, I recommend you look here: [spring boot external configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)